# how to call function in Extension in swift?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I'm making an app but I'm confused about how to call the function in the extension file.

This is the code that I'm trying to call the function from the extension.

```
import UIKit

class RecipeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var commnetLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTypeLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    func configureView(recipe: RecipeData){
    
        commnetLabel.text = recipe.comment
        recipeImageView.setImage(imageUrl: recipe.imageUrl)
    //  dateLabel.text = recipe.recordedAt => get something like 2020-10-01 11:08:42

        dateLabel.text = setTemplate(strDate: recipe.recordedAt)
        recipeTypeLabel.text = recipe.recipeType

    }

}
```

In the configureView function, I used to write `dateLabel.text = recipe.recordedAt`to show the date to the app. I'm now trying to change how it is displayed, so I created an extension.

```
import Foundation

extension DateFormatter {

    func setTemplate (strDate: String) -> String {
    
    
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "ydMMM", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "ja_JP"))
    
        let result = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    
        return result
    }
}
```

I thought writing `dateLabel.text = setTemplate(strDate: recipe.recordedAt)` in configureView function enables to call setTemplate function and change my dateLabel's text. However, currently I'm getting

> Use of unresolved identifier 'setTemplate'

and I'm confused about why and how to access to setTemplate function.

Could anyone tell me why I'm getting the error and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to extend `RecipeTableViewCell`, not `DateFormatter`.

```
extension RecipeTableViewCell {
    func setTemplate(strDate: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "ydMMM", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "ja_JP"))
        let result = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    
        return result
    }
}
```

If you extend `DateFormatter`, the function `setTemplate` is added to the class `DateFormatter` -- you can't access it from `RecipeTableViewCell`. But if you really wanted to extend `DateFormatter`, you could do it like this:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    func setTemplate(strDate: String) -> String {
        self.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "ydMMM", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "ja_JP"))
        let result = self.string(from: Date())

        return result
    }
}

/// usage:
let formatter = DateFormatter()
dateLabel.text = formatter.setTemplate(strDate: recipe.recordedAt)
```

Extending `DateFormatter` directly lets you access `setTemplate` from anywhere (not just `RecipeTableViewCell`), so you might want to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I didn't really understand what extension is, but now I get it thanks to your explanation. I have another question. Like the case above, do you use the extension and write a method (setTemplate), or do you create another class or struct and create method in it?

Comment: It's much easier to make an extension. Classes/structs are more for when you need to store data (extensions can't contain stored properties).

Answer (score 1):

Your function is correct but you just need to make it static. Just tested in PLayground and it worked.

```
extension DateFormatter {

 static func setTemplate (strDate: String) -> String {


    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "ydMMM", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "ja_JP"))

    let result = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    return result
 }
}
```